# No me rellena el spinner -Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

El caso es que estoy intentando rellenar el `spinner` con los nombres de los `partners`, pero cuando la sentencia `Select` ;parece ser que no devuelve nada y no me rellena. Llevo un rato buscando que puedo estar haciendo mal pero no encuentro mi fallo. 
Mi código:

```
 public void rellenarSpinner() {
    Cursor cursor;
    Spinner sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPartners);
    BDCarSecurity conexion = new BDCarSecurity(getApplicationContext(), "BDComerciales", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = conexion.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select * from Partners";
    String provisional;
     try {
         cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             do {
                 provisional = cursor.getString(1);
                 adapter.add(provisional);

             } while (cursor.moveToNext());
             adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
             sItems.setAdapter(adapter);
         }
         cursor.close();
         db.close();
     }catch (Exception e){
         Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```

y esta es la tabla:

```
String sqlCreatePartners =    "CREATE TABLE Partners (PartnerID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,Nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, Apellidos VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL, Email VARCHAR(30)  UNIQUE NOT NULL, Telefono VARCHAR(9)  UNIQUE NOT NULL, Empresa VARCHAR(20), Direccion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ComercialID INTEGER,FOREIGN KEY(ComercialID) REFERENCES Comerciales(ComercialID))";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomendaria lo hicieras en dos partes, 1 en donde haces la consulta a la base y otra donde seteas los datos al spinner, lo cual quedaría así:

```
//obteniendo los datos 
public ArrayList<String> getData() {
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor;
    BDCarSecurity conexion = new BDCarSecurity(getApplicationContext(), "BDComerciales", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String query = "select * from Partners";
    String provisional;
    db = conexion.getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                provisional = cursor.getString(1);
                data.add(provisional);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return data;
}

//seteando los datos
public void rellenarSpinner() {
    Spinner sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPartners);
    ArrayList<String> datos = getData();
    if (datos.size() > 0) {
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getData());
        sItems.setAdapter(adapter);

    } else {
        //toast diciendo que no hay datos
    }

}
```

Comment: me seguía sin funcionar haciendo lo que tu me dices pero cambien el getApplicationContext() por this y me funcionó, xD y no se porque